# React Modal always get overlapped

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, modal-dialog

I have some problem in creating react modal,
The modal that i created is always overlapped by the next rendered component,
The modal itself is created on the  component, it is triggered by clicking a card in that component.

```
   <Experience />
   <About />
   <Works className="relative onTop" />
   <div className="relative z-0">
      <Contact />
     <StarsCanvas />
   </div>
```

The  is always overlapping the modal, but if i replace it on top of the  component, it works. Not only , if i put other component, such as  below the  it also overlapped the modal. I also have put z-index = 9999 in my css, but it still doesnt work. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: A `z-index` of 0 places the element behind other elements in the stacking order. If you want the modal to appear above other components, you need to ensure that the `z-index` property of the modal and its parent elements is higher than the components you want to overlay.

Answer (score 0):

The div that encloses the corresponding component must be removed. This is how I managed it, try it like this:

```
<Experience />
<About />
<Works className="relative onTop" />
<Contact />
<StarsCanvas />
```